# pandoc-citeproc does not seem to handle multiple authors well

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc

Consider this BibTeX-entry:

```
@Article{owenæs16,
  author =   {J F Owe and H Næss and　I O Gjerde and
                  J E Bødtker and O-B Tysnes},
  title =    {Utredning ved mistenkt kronisk utmattelsessyndrom/
                  myalgisk encefalopati},
  journal =      {Tidsskrift for Den norske Legeforening},
  year =     2016,
  volume =   136,
  number =   3,
  pages =    {227–232}}
```

Using any of several different .csl files, pandoc renders this in the bibliography:

```
Owe, J. F., O Gjerde, H. N. and　I, Bødtker, J. E., & Tysnes, O.-B.
```

Rather than, say, Owe, J. F et al. Note the mixture of "and" and "&".

In this instance, I have used

http://www.zotero.org/styles/apa-5th-edition

But the default renders essentially the same, and alternative apalike styles, generate essentially the same.

Any and all help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: seems like there is an unbreakable space in your bibtex file between "and" and "I O Gjerde".

Comment: Indeed there is. Thank you, and my apologies, everybody.